# Android - Clean char array quickly and effectively

Tags: java, android, char, arrays

Is it possible to clean a char array in Java (Android) quickly and effectively? Make an other loop on the treatment seem to be to much heavy to be an optimised solution, doesn't it ?

It's strange but it is impossible to find such a solution in Java on the internet without having to subscribe to a pay site ..

Thank's to your attention

Comment: What does "cleaning a char array mean"? Setting all its values to 0? If so, looping is the only way.

Comment: "cleaning" mean re-initialize each values of this array like when it was created. I think, in java each values of a char array are initalized to '\0' in java. But looping +20000 values each frames seem to be an un optimised solutuion, that's why I would like to know if a better solution exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to clear a char array in the first place?

Most functions that want a char array to put some data in it (IO read, etc..) return the length of data that was put in, so you can disregard the rest of the data in char array.

Comment: Yes I know, but I meet some troubles in writing data to a file using with an char array. That's why I wanted to make sure that my troubles doesn't come from this array. I know writing over data is enough, but I wanted to be sure the problem doesn't come from there. And any solutions are findable about this subject java on the internet

Comment: You give me the solution Peter, thank you. I wrote my char array regardless the length of data got. It caused some troubles on the file maked with this array. No it works, thank's again

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Arrays.fill(yourArray, ' ');// or any other char instead of ' '
```

`Arrays` class belongs to the `java.util` package. It uses generics so you can fill any kind of array.

Comment: Keep in mind that `fill` method will loop through your array. This is just a shortcut... but won't solve your performance problems.

Comment: I think so. But if any solution exists this way has at least the advantage streamlined the code

Answer (score 0):

Use a **boolean** to indicate that your array is invalid.

Comment: I don't understand why I would do that ? How can know if my array is valid or not ? An array contains characters, only their using may be correct or not

Comment: And how do you know when to clear the array? Your array is either cleared or not cleared - use a boolean to represent this (instead of actually 'clearing').

Comment: This array is filled each frames by datas, so its cleaning ensures that the next data insertion will not corrupted by remaining bits of the previous frame

Comment: I don't know.. but as bits of this array will be overwritten hundreds of thousands of times, I prefer clean it because of troubles generated by the content transfered by this array

Comment: You don't have to worry about this in Java.

Comment: I'm used to coding in C/C++, thank's for your advices. In the end the problem was that : I wrote my char array regardless the length of data got. Corrupted data caused some troubles on the file maked with this array. No its work, thank's again

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know whether predetermine the size of an array which will be completed by  various data sizes, or let it size evolve according to the reception is the best way? This is intended to have the fastest processing.
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer to this question is to set each character of the char[] to null character by doing:

```
Arrays.fill(buffer, (char)0);
```

Or

```
Arrays.fill(buffer, '\0');
```

Doing `Arrays.fill(buffer, '0');` will fill all the char[] with the character '0' instead of the null character.